# Assertion failure using MPI_Gather

Tags: c, malloc, mpi

I am trying to write MPI C code that repeatedly performs a calculation and saves its outcome into a single array for outputting less frequently. Example code below (the size of var, 200, is sufficient for the number of CPUs in use):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

float *phie, *phitemp, var[200];
int time=0, gatherphi=10, gatherfile = 200, j, iter=0, lephie, x;
int nelecrank = 2, size, rank, Tmax = 2000;
FILE *out;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) ;

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

lephie = gatherfile/gatherphi; // number of runs of calculation before output

// allocate memory
//printf("%d Before malloc.\n", rank);
if (rank==1) phie=(float *) malloc(nelecrank*size*gatherfile/gatherphi*sizeof(float));
phitemp=(float *) malloc(nelecrank*sizeof(float));
//printf("%d After malloc.\n", rank);

for(j=0;j<200;j++) var[j]=rank;

for(time=0;time<Tmax;time++){
if (!time%gatherphi) {// do calculation

  for (j=0;j<nelecrank;j++) { // each processor does the calculation nelecrank times
              phitemp[j]=0; 
              for (x = 0; x<=4; x++) {
                  phitemp[j]=phitemp[j]+var[rank+j*size];
                  }
              } 
         } // end of j for loop
         printf("iter: %d, %d Before MPI_Gather.\n", iter, rank);
         MPI_Gather(phitemp, nelecrank, MPI_FLOAT, phie+iter*nelecrank*size*sizeof(float), nelecrank, MPI_FLOAT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         iter++;
     } // end of gatherphi condition

if (time % gatherfile) { //output result of calculation
  iter=0;
  if (rank==1) {
              out = fopen ("output.txt", "wt+");
              if (out == NULL) {
                  printf("Could not open output file.\n");
                  exit(1);
                  }
              else  printf("Have opened output file.\n");
              for (j=0;j<nelecrank*size*lephie;j++) {
                      fprintf(out,"%f ",*(phie+j*sizeof(float)));
                  }
              fclose(out);
              }
   } // end of file output

if (rank==1) {
      if (phie) free (phie);
      }
if (phitemp) free (phitemp);
MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

It gives me repeated memory allocation problems until it finally exits. I am not experienced using memory allocation in MPI - can you help?

Many thanks,
Marta

Comment: Can you describe the exact nature of your "repeated memory allocation problems"? Do you not get enough memory allocated? Do you get a SIGSEGV for illegal memory access? Do you get a double free?

Comment: Here it is:MPT ERROR: rank:1, function:MPI_GATHER, Message truncated on receive: An application bug caused the sender to send too much data
MPT ERROR: Rank 1(g:1) is aborting with error code 0.
 Process ID: 580144, Host: sgiuv, Program: /home/mv12/Code/Fibrosisnew/example
 MPT Version: SGI MPT 2.15  11/13/16 02:05:30

MPT: --------stack traceback-------
MPT: Attaching to program: /proc/580144/exe, process 580144

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addressing Memory in MPI\_Gather C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985758/addressing-memory-in-mpi-gather-c) Please do not open multiple questions about the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `phie` is not big enough.

You `malloc`ed `nelecrank*size*gatherfile/gatherphi*sizeof(float)=80*sizeof(float)` memory for `phie`.

But, your `MPI_Gather` usage requires `iter*nelecrank*size*sizeof(float)+nelecrank*size*sizeof(float)` memory. `iter` takes a maximum value of `nelecrank*Tmax-1`, so `phie` needs to be `(nelecrank*Tmax-1)*nelecrank*size*sizeof(float)+nelecrank*size*sizeof(float)`, which is around `8000*size*sizeof(float)` large.

Maybe you want to reset `iter=0` in your loop somewhere?