# Addressing Memory in MPI_Gather C

Tags: c, malloc, mpi, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to pass on data to `MPI_Gather`. I allocate memory as follows:

```
float *phie, *phitemp;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

phitemp=(float *) malloc(20*sizeof(float));
if (rank==1) phie=(float *) malloc(itermax*20*size*sizeof(float));
```

and then get all processes to send data to rank 1 using `MPI_Gather()` as below:

```
for (iter=0;iter<itermax;iter++) {    
   MPI_Gather((float *) phitemp, 20, MPI_FLOAT, (float *) (phie+iter*20*size*sizeof(float)), 20, MPI_FLOAT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   iter=0;
```

}

I get error messages suggesting I am not allocating memory appropriately.

Comment: Adding on my question. I use the variable iter to move the address of the receive buffer in MPI_Gather(). iter may have different values in different processors. Which one is used in the MPI_Gather function? The one for the processor that receives the data? If so, how can I ensure the different processors are waiting for it?

Comment: Please add the exact wording of the specific error message to your question!

Comment: If you add any more questions, please use the edit function and put the additional questions in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is done on the size of word the pointer is pointing to. Since `phie` is a `float *`, the `sizeof(float)` in `phie+iter*20*size*sizeof(float)` is redundant and you are going outside of the valid memory.

Remove the `sizeof(float`), or better change it to a clearer array indexing: `&(phie[iter * 20 * size])`

You should also remove all the pointer casts, they are all redundant and can hide issues. You should only cast when you know that you need it.

Regarding your additional question: The `recvbuf` parameter of `MPI_Gather` is only significant at the root process. Therefore only the `iter` of the root process matters. Nevertheless since all your processes go through the same loop of running `MPI_Gather`, and they cannot overtake each other, they will always have the same `iter` during matching gathers.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed that, but the errors remain.

Comment: If MPI_Gather does not allow the processes to overtake each other, how can inserting an output line before the MPI_Gather command printf("iter: %d, processor: %d before MPI_Gather.\n", iter, rank);
give this output?
iter: 0, processor: 0 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 0, processor: 1 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 0, processor: 2 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 0, processor: 3 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 1, processor: 0 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 1, processor: 1 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 2, processor: 1 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 3, processor: 1 before MPI_Gather.
iter: 4, processor: 1 before MPI_Gathe

Comment: Please edit a fixed [mcve] (read that page carefully) into your question for any further debugging attempts.

Comment: The operations cannot overtake each other, means only that they will match in order. But the control flow on the ranks is not necessarily in sync - `MPI_Gather` does not imply a barrier. Also there is no guarntee whatsover on how stdout from different ranks is merged.

Comment: That was a small bug that I have since fixed. Thank you for your clarification earlier: that was the main issue I was facing.